# What are good resources to read up on funding policies, especially pertaining to biology in the United States?

Tags: funding, united-states, reference-request, biology

I am a biology PhD. student in the United States. I would like to know a little bit more on how to navigate the politics and processes that guide grant funding. In addition to this I am looking for good resources to keep up with news that might impact or change these policies. I guess in short, what are some reputable sites, blogs, news sources, literature or books to help with this?

By tracking policy I meant any good resources that track any legislature or incentives that are being passed that might impact the amount of money going into grant funding. I am also just genuinely interested in the grant funding process or any insightful resources on how to best navigate the whole process.

Comment: What kind of funding policies? What country are you in? What field?

Comment: I am in a biology PhD. Program. By tracking policy I meant any good resources that track any legislature or incentives that are being passed that might impact the amount of money going into grant funding. I am also just genuinely interested in the grant funding process or any insightful resources on how to best navigate the whole process.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Sorry should read a little more carefully. US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few blogs that I find highly informative regarding the politics, changes, and historical trends affecting science funding in the United States.

[Drugmonkey](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/) often blogs about the NIH. Recent examples include:

- [NCI will ease that difficult transition to postdoc](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/2015/12/24/nci-will-ease-that-difficult-transition-to-postdoc/)
- [Congress let the NIH drop the HIV/AIDS set-aside: Implications for NIDA?](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/2015/12/15/congress-let-the-nih-drop-the-hivaids-set-aside-implications-for-nida/)
- [RFAs do not narrow the NIH portfolio, quite the opposite.](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/2015/11/06/rfas-do-not-narrow-the-nih-portfolio-quite-the-opposite/)
- [NIH grant application changes are in the offing](http://drugmonkey.scientopia.org/2015/10/16/nih-grant-changes-in-the-offing/)

[Prof-like Substance](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/) blogs a fair bit about goings-on affecting the NSF, especially [IOS](http://www.nsf.gov/div/index.jsp?div=IOS) and [DEB](http://www.nsf.gov/div/index.jsp?div=DEB) divisions and also generally the [BIO](http://www.nsf.gov/dir/index.jsp?org=BIO) directorate, including historical trends and recent changes in proposal and funding procedures. Recent examples:

- [Your DEB panel summary will look a bit different this year](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/2015/11/04/your-deb-panel-summary-will-look-a-bit-different-this-year/)
- [What you learn from reviewing a batch of proposals](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/2015/10/06/what-you-learn-from-reviewing-a-batch-of-proposals/)
- [My love/hate relationship with NSF preproposals](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/2015/07/22/my-lovehate-relationship-with-nsf-preproposals/)
- [How do we make NSF science more sustainable?](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/2015/06/05/how-do-we-make-nsf-science-more-sustainable/)
- [Some depressing NSF DEB stats](http://proflikesubstance.scientopia.org/2015/05/07/some-depressing-nsf-deb-stats/)

There's also the blog of the [NIH Office of Extramural Research](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/category/blog/), which is often very informative. I especially appreciate the posts that reveal data about internal workings and funding patterns of the NIH. Examples:

- [Understanding the Capacity of NIH’s Peer Review System](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2015/07/30/understanding-capacity-peer-review/)
- [What are the Chances of Getting Funded?](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2015/06/29/what-are-the-chances-of-getting-funded/)
- [Lab Size and Strategic Support of Science: Thoughts on Finding the Right Mix](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2015/11/06/lab-size-and-strategic-support-of-science-thoughts-on-finding-the-right-mix/)
- [Update on the Postdoctoral Benefit Survey](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2015/11/30/update-postdoctoral-benefit-survey/)

[Science Insider](http://news.sciencemag.org/scienceinsider) reports on science policy. Examples include:

- [Decision to end monkey experiments based on finances, not animal rights, NIH says](http://news.sciencemag.org/plants-animals/2015/12/decision-end-controversial-monkey-experiments-based-finances-not-animal)
- [NIH releases first agency-wide strategic plan in 2 decades](http://news.sciencemag.org/scientific-community/2015/12/nih-releases-first-agency-wide-strategic-plan-2-decades)
- [Budget agreement boosts U.S. science](http://news.sciencemag.org/funding/2015/12/budget-agreement-boosts-u-s-science)

Comment: Thank you this is an excellent start. Just what I was looking for!